# Running rospy dependent file in Github Actions

Tags: ros, github-actions, rospy

I'm trying to implement CI with Github Actions to a repository. In the workflow, I would like to run a test script using `pytest`. However, the test script and the script it is testing had a `rospy` dependency, although the dependency is not vital to the test, where it is publishing the result of certain calculation (`node.Publisher` is mocked using `pytest`).

I'm still new to ROS and I am a bit confused about what I need to install. Do I need to install the whole ROS library for the test or do I only need to install `rospy`? What is the best way to install the package and add it to the path in Github Actions?

I tried `sudo apt-get install -y python-rospy`, but the package is not detected by python with `ImportError: No module named rospy`.

I am running the test in Ubuntu 18.04.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You might want to check that your python executable is using python2, not "python"==python3. ROS in Ubuntu 18 still uses python2, so installing python-rospy may not make it visible to the path for python3.

Comment: I tested it, the executable ran on Python 2.7.18, so the version should be correct